# Gradle war - duplicated classes on classpath

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, spring-boot, cxf

I've got following gradle compile dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.6'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.6'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:3.1.6'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:2.5.11'
```

And after execute war task I've got ReflectionUtil class from both: org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:2.5.11 and org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.1.6

It results in noSuchMethodException because Spring uses wrong class.

How can I avoid it, and keep both dependencies?
I've experimented with different versions, etc. but without success.

Comment: Spring itself doesn't do anything with CXF. What's the stacktrace of the `NoSuchMethodError`?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...]: Factory method '...' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo.getFirstMessagePart()Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/MessagePartInfo;

Comment: It's hard to read in a comment. Can you please edit your question and include the full stack trace instead?

Comment: Did you solve? I have same problem